# Spark CSV : Parse files deliminated by Ascii æ (Hex E6)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

I have large data files deliminated by ASCII character æ (Hex E6). My code snipped for parsing the file is as follows ,but seems the parser does not slit values properly (I use Spark 2.4.1)

```
implicit class DataFrameReadImplicits (dataFrameReader: DataFrameReader) {
     def readTeradataCSV(schema: StructType, path: String) : DataFrame = {
        dataFrameReader.option("delimiter", "\u00E6")
          .option("header", "false")
          .option("inferSchema", "false")
          .option("multiLine","true")
          .option("encoding", "UTF-8")
          .schema(schema)
          .csv(path)
     }
  }
```

Sample file :
https://gist.github.com/ashikaumanga/c2161eee07da9b10052a4e53bc4c567e

Any tips how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: can you add some sample data ?

Comment: @Srinivas added screenshot

Comment: what output are you getting, is it nulls  ?

Comment: yes, I get nulls.I also tried removing surrounding double-quotations.. result is the same

Comment: ok, now i got it. your schema is not matching .. can you try without schema option .. ?

Comment: yes.i tried without Schema.. its the same.. everything read as a one column without splitting

Comment: can you add two lines of sample data .. just for testing ?

Comment: @Srinivas here is a sample file : https://gist.github.com/ashikaumanga/c2161eee07da9b10052a4e53bc4c567e

Comment: @Srinivas btw,I created sample CSV data with Ascii 001 (u0001) as the deliminator and that file parsed properly. Seems the parser doesn't work for Extended Ascii values ( > 125)

Comment: I am able to parse your data .. can you post your schema ??

Comment: ```
scala> spark.read.readTeradataCSV("/tmp/data").printSchema
root
 |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c5: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c6: string (nullable = true)
 ... 

```

Comment: ok, i think that could be the reason why it is not parsing properly .. :)

Comment: @Srinivas seems my CSV charset is  iso-8859-1. I think in the gist file its utf-8